# c++ regex match_results life cycle

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

The first test passes, while the second fails.

```
TEST_METHOD(ShouldMatchText) {
    std::wsmatch match;
    std::wstring text(L"abc");
    std::regex_match(text, match, std::wregex(L"(.*)"));
    Assert::AreEqual(std::wstring(L"abc"), std::wstring(match[1]));
}

TEST_METHOD(ShouldMatchText2) {
    std::wsmatch match;
    {
        std::wstring text(L"abc");
        std::regex_match(text, match, std::wregex(L"(.*)"));
    }
    Assert::AreEqual(std::wstring(L"abc"), std::wstring(match[1]));
}
```

It seems that `match_results` refers to matching string internally. Is there a way to make `math_results` valid even after the matching string de-allocated? Because in my real case, the matching string is `temp`, and I do want to use the matched groups later in other scopes.

Extension of existing match_results is preferable if possible, other solutions like using a vector to hold the groups will lose information.

---

Just noticed the explanation from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results

> This is a specialized allocator-aware container. It can only be
>   default created, obtained from std::regex_iterator, or modified by
>   std::regex_search or std::regex_match. Because std::match_results
>   holds std::sub_matches, each of which is a pair of iterators into the
>   original character sequence that was matched, it's undefined behavior
>   to examine std::match_results if the original character sequence was
>   destroyed or iterators to it were invalidated for other reasons.

Comment: Indexing match_result, returns a reference to an object of type sub_match, where the string can be obtained. I'm checking now but not sure that sub_match doesn't just contain pointers into the original string, or actually creates a string.

Comment: The match_results object must exist in some global context to be referenced elsewhere. You could always make a new class that encapsulates a target string, regex,  regex_match function, and match results objects. Something like RXMatch(); Can set a new regex via RXMatch.SetRx();, Can match via RXMatch.Match( string& strTarget) where m_sTarget = strTarget;, then call match. Sort of like a shadow buffer of the target. Then just pass around RXMatch object.